# Laravel and axios clear Form after submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, laravel-5.4, axios

In my Laravel app i'm submitting a form with vue and axios.
After the submit i want to clear the input field in the form, but it wont work.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" v-on:submit.prevent="addPost">
  <textarea id="post_area" v-model="content"></textarea>
  .....
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
  content: '',
  posts: []
},

......

.then(function (response) {
   if(response.status===200) {
      //reload posts
      app.posts = response.data;
      this.content = '';
   }
})
```

It just wont clear out the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` does not point to the vue instance in your Promise's success callback

Use a arrow function instead. Arrow function binds the value of `this` lexically

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
  content: '',
  posts: []
},

......

.then( (response) => {
   if(response.status===200) {
      //reload posts
      app.posts = response.data;
      this.content = '';
   }
})
```

Or create a local variable pointing the correct vue instance  and use it to access your data property like this:

```
methods:{
    addPost(){
        var vm = this;

        //.....axios post
         .then( (response) => {
            if(response.status===200) {
                //reload posts
                app.posts = response.data;
                vm.content = '';
            }
        }) 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That one was to simple.